# Why does one circuit work but not the other in LTspice?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

Newb here having trouble. I have two identical circuits built in LTspice. Once works fine, and the one pictured here does not. Note the ??? marks on the drawing, they should be DC voltages. I know they are there because you can see and measure them on the Trace display. Why is one circuit happy, and this one is not?

Edit added second circuit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can we see the other circuit too?

Comment: Because you are doing the transient analysis and this is why you do not see DC voltages. "at the wires". To be able to see DC voltage "at the wires" you need to use DC op pnt analysis instead.

Comment: @G36 Transient analysis will show the DC voltages over time, even if they are steady-state.

Comment: Please label the nodes (fuction key F4). V(n002) doesn't mean much if you don't know where the node is. On the graph, be sure the left side is shown so we can see the values of the y-axis.

Comment: @qrk Not for all the circuits. Because the "wire voltages" are coming from operating point analysis that is done before the transient.

Comment: I added the second circuit. The only difference is the Op-Amp. 

I did try to use DC OP Pnt but does not work, just a box with a list of nodes.

Comment: Perhaps a change was made that unlinked the operating points from the nodes. Try cutting the operating points and re-adding them by right clicking on the nodes and selecting place .op label from the menu.

Comment: The circuits are not identical. R4 has different values.  U3 is wired differently. The 1 ohm resistor is labeled R14 in one circuit and R16 in the other. It is also in parallel with R11 making R11 useless. What does the circuit do? According to the voltages in the second circuit, there is about 14 volts across R16 implying a current of 14 amperes which seems too large.

Comment: FWIW, I entered the entire first circuit in as shown, with the same models (AFAIK) and it shows voltages after a fraction of a second calculation.

Comment: You could also try to change in the Control Panel (SPICE tab) the solver engine--->normal/alternate.

Comment: @Dereck Post the netlists for both, please.

Comment: @Barry, it is a CV 12-volt, 30-amp with a Foldback DC Power Supply and battery charger. It works perfectly. The extra circuitry around U3 is a Soft Turn-On circuit. R1 and R16 you refer to are my Loads I use to vary the load from Open to Short and everything in between to observe it working. R11 is the Bleeder Resistor for the capacitor. Are there any more intelligent comments?